# Having an Issue with Multer/Express/MongoDB - File saved to DB correctly, 404 error in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to figure out, despite a few hours of searching for an answer online. I'm using Node, Express, MongoDB, Multer and EJS templates and I'm attempting to save an image to the DB, and then use it in one of my views.

I was first having trouble getting the file to save to the DB correctly, but with the help of this site, I was able to work through that. But my issue now is when I try to use this in one of my views, **I keep getting a weird 404 error that has a strange path**:

> CANNOT GET:
>   http://localhost:3090/project/%7B%20contentType:%20'image/png',%20%20data:%…b%2047%2044%2000%20ff%2000%20ff%2000%20ff%20a0%20bd%20a7%20...%20%3E%20%7D
>   404 (Not Found)

This made me think it wasn't correctly saved in the DB, but in Robomongo, it looks like this, which seems correct to me:

[image: type]

So, I can see that it has my content type in the URL, which is clearly a mistake, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

I have some previously added images to that file that aren't saved to the DB, and those show just fine using the same template, so the path should be correct.

Many thanks to you all in advance!!

My Index.JS file:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const router = require('./router');


//App Setup

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));



router(app);


//DB Setup
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/projectsApp');
    mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to mongodb server.');
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(names);
    }
   });
})




//Server Setup

const port = process.env.PORT || 3090;
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

router.js file:

```
const Project = require('./models/project');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');



var upload = multer({ dest: './public/img' })


module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    Project.find({}, (err, projects) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('admin', {projects: projects});
        }
    })
});

app.post('/admin', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.file);
        newProj = {
            title: req.body.title,
            tech: req.body.tech,
            url: req.body.url,
            shortDescription: req.body.shortDescription,
            longDescription: req.body.longDescription,
            image: { data: fs.readFileSync(req.file.path), contentType: 'image/png' }
        };


        Project.create(newProj, (err, proj) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(proj);
                    res.redirect("/");
                }
        });

});



}
```

and finally, the view, just in case:

```
<% include ./partials/header%>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="project-div">
            <h1><%= project.title%></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src='<%= project.image%>'/>

            <hr />
            <span><strong>URL: </strong> <a href="<%= project.url%>"><%= project.url%></a></span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to output the object holding the image data directly in your template. This won't work because that's simply not how html work...

I would recommend setting up another route for the image, and then referring to that image.

```
app.get('/admin/projects/:id/image', (req, res, next) => {
  Project.find({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (result.length === 0) return next()

    res.set('Content-Type', result[0].contentType)
    res.send(result[0].data)
  })
})
```

and then using that url in your template:

```
...

<img src="/admin/projects/<%= project._id %>/image" />

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!